# Why did Cannon Fodder on the SNES not use the voice in the intro song?

Tags: snes, amiga, cannon-fodder

In the Amiga original of *Cannon Fodder*, you can hear a voice singing short phrases repeatedly over the instrumental music.

In the SNES port, they had removed the voices and only kept the (great) tune.

But why? Even the NES was capable of using short speech samples, and the SNES had far superior audio capabilities and could easily (in my mind) have kept the sound samples to make the song faithful to its original.

Note that the song is not like an entire .WAV file, but extremely short words or short phrases as individual files which are just repeated at specific places in the song, so it would have taken up very little space. Were bulk ROM prices really so high that even something like that had to be sacrificed?

Or was it an entirely non-technical decision, such as they thought it sounded better without the voices? Or it was "too violent" or something to hear the voice? I'm just making guesses since it doesn't seem like a technical one to me.

Comment: I can't find any supporting documentation, but if I recall Nintendo baulked at the lyrics: e.g. "war has never been so much fun", "go to your brother, kill him with your gun", etc.